# Multiple web2py devices on one Lan

Tags: raspberry-pi, web2py

This is a very high level question but I would appreciate some input so I know if I am barking up the right tree.

I am looking to install multiple Raspberry Pis on to a LAN that all collect temp readings and perform basic actions.

They can all be running web2py if needed with their own code but I would like them to communicate between each other as some temperature readings might trigger events on other Pis. I would also like one master webpage if possible displaying all of the results.

Is web2py the right option for this or is there another preferred method?

Many thanks for your thoughts.

T

Comment: If i would build this i would let the pi's talk to each other over zeromq. Then i would have a redis key value store where they push their data to, then i would let one read the data from redis and display it as a webpage.

Comment: Many thanks for your input. Those look like good options. If I could pick your brain a little more, would I need to run a python script continuously on  main Pi that is receiving the messages over ZeroMQ that writes the messages in to Redis. Something like this.
`

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

while True:
    #  Wait for next request from client
    message = socket.recv()
    r.set('key, message)

    time.sleep(1) 
`

Comment: Looks like a solution. 
I see no need for `time.sleep` here, because `socket.recv()` blocks until a new message is available. The next think you should think of is to use an redis list, but this depends an what you want to archive.
Remember the redis function `keys` is just for development and will block your redis instance (http://redis.io/commands/keys).